# Sharing Visual Studio Marketplace Extension with DevOps Server instance

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I created a Visual Studio Marketplace extension, uploaded it onto https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers, and have it ready to go. According to the documentation, my next step is to "share" it with the organization of my choice.

However, the only options are organizations with the route https://dev.azure.com/ which is not our route url since we are on Azure DevOps 2020 Server (our route is https://devops.OurCompany...) I cannot seem to change the route url in their UI, and every variation of our url I've entered either is not found or bad formatting. Any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: No need to share, check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it showed, only 'organization' can be shared with.

And if the extension is not public, I think it will not be able to directly download in marketplace, you need to make it public and then download it.

**Or you can follow the below simple steps to directly use the extension you created.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]